# SQL Temp Table scoped only to the Proc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a table, with many indexes that is scoped only to the running sproc.

I tried a table variable, but this doesn't seem to support indexes.  A local temp table seems to create a 'real' table, and need to be explicitly dropped at the end of the proc, from which I'm inferring that it's also shared across concurrent runs and so would break.

What can I use to store data with indexes that is scoped only to the indicidual instance of the running sproc?

Comment: A local temp table (single # prefix) is scoped for the current connection and will not conflict with concurrent sessions.

Comment: Table variables do support primary key and unique constraints and, in SQL 2014 and later versions, indexes.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to worry about dropping the table.  SQL Server does that automatically.  As explained in the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(v=sql.110).aspx):

> - A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped automatically when the stored procedure is finished. The table can be
>     referenced by any nested stored procedures executed by the stored
>     procedure that created the table. The table cannot be referenced by
>     the process that called the stored procedure that created the table.

This is a result of the scoping rules for access to the temporary table.

I will admit, that in practice, I tend to explicitly drop temporary tables in stored procedures. The differences among:

- `create table temp`
- `create table #temp`
- `create table ##temp`

are all too similar to rely on the fact that the second is dropped automatically, but the first and third are not.  However, this is my "problem" and not a best practice.

Comment: I think he should worry, if there is some inserts and updates on the created #temp table, and then while the process still not yet finished, another call occurred for the stored procedure!? BOOM all data smashed, I think best approach to use a #temp + UserKey combination, but he needs to run dynamic queries

Comment: @HadiHassan . . . Read the documentation.  SQL Server protects against that eventuality.  In fact, it has an awkward length on the temporary table name (116 characters) as opposed to 128 characters for a regular table.

Comment: :P I should not debate with 0.5M reputation Guy !!, I updated my answer with a test and you were right, it seems that the temp table inside the stored procedure acts like local variable

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'll ty again.  My tests weren't inside a sproc, so that could account for it's  persistance after the script was run.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

The answer is don't worry at all since the temp table will be as if it was a local variable inside the stored procedure.

I wanted to make sure if the doubt I had was correct or not, so I made this test

```
create procedure TestTempData
as
begin
    declare @date datetime = getdate()
    if object_id('#testing') is not null
        drop table #testing
    create table #testing(
        Id int identity(1,1),
        [Date] datetime
    )

    print 'run at ' + format(@date,'HH:mm:ss')

    insert into #testing([Date]) values
    (dateadd(second,10,getdate())),
    (dateadd(second,20,getdate())),
    (dateadd(second,30,getdate()))
    waitfor delay '00:00:15'
    select * from #testing
end
```

then I ran this query

```
exec TestTempData

waitfor delay '00:00:02'

exec TestTempData
```

the result came as

```
run at 14:57:39
Id  Date
1   2016-09-21 14:57:49.117
2   2016-09-21 14:57:59.117
3   2016-09-21 14:58:09.117
```

the second result

```
run at 14:57:56
Id  Date
1   2016-09-21 14:58:06.113
2   2016-09-21 14:58:16.113
3   2016-09-21 14:58:26.113
```

> If the concurrent runs will effect the #temp table, both results
>   should be the same which was not the case, It seems that the temp
>   table inside stored procedure acts like a local variable inside a
>   method.

**Before chatting with Gordon Linoff**

Since you mentioned that the temp table is shared across concurrent runs, your temp table should be unique for the current run.

Your stored procedure should look like this

```
create procedure YourProc(@userId int)
as
begin
   if object_id('#temp' + @userId) IS NOT NULL
       execute( 'DROP TABLE #temp' + @userId +'')
    ...
    execute('insert into #temp' + @userId + 'values(...')
end
```

The above solution will ensure that no conflict will occur and no data will be lost since each execution will be unique per userId

you don't need to drop the table when you finish because it will be dropped automatically by it self

Hope this will help you